# How to display the entire output and not shortened versions

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, pandas, data-science-model

I'm trying to display all the columns in my dataset that have `NaN` values:

`print(train.isnull().sum())`

The output that I get is this:

```
Id                0
MSSubClass        0
MSZoning          0
LotFrontage       0
LotArea           0
Street            0
Alley             0
LotShape          0
LandContour       0
Utilities         0
LotConfig         0
LandSlope         0
Neighborhood      0
Condition1        0
Condition2        0
BldgType          0
HouseStyle        0
OverallQual       0
OverallCond       0
YearBuilt         0
YearRemodAdd      0
RoofStyle         0
RoofMatl          0
Exterior1st       0
Exterior2nd       0
MasVnrType        8
MasVnrArea        0
ExterQual         0
ExterCond         0
Foundation        0
                 ..
BedroomAbvGr      0
KitchenAbvGr      0
KitchenQual       0
TotRmsAbvGrd      0
Functional        0
Fireplaces        0
FireplaceQu       0
GarageType        0
GarageYrBlt      81
GarageFinish      0
GarageCars        0
GarageArea        0
GarageQual        0
GarageCond        0
PavedDrive        0
WoodDeckSF        0
OpenPorchSF       0
EnclosedPorch     0
3SsnPorch         0
ScreenPorch       0
PoolArea          0
PoolQC            0
Fence             0
MiscFeature       0
MiscVal           0
MoSold            0
YrSold            0
SaleType          0
SaleCondition     0
SalePrice         0
Length: 81, dtype: int64
```

I actually want to see the entire output and not a shortened version with `..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to [Marce's](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/77148/marce) answer, you can display all the rows without finding `N` by using:

```
with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", -1):
    display(train.isnull().sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a `Pandas` dataframe. In that case, something like

`pd.options.display.max_rows = N`

should work. Here, `N` is a number bigger than the number of rows you want to print and `pd` comes from `import pandas as pd`.

Comment: Actually its Boston.

Comment: what is Boston? what type of object is your `train` variable?